# How to retrieve my foreign key fields value in json with jpa?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a database with some entities, and when I try to make a query and get the data in a JSON array, I only get the fields which are not foreign keys, the ones which are foreign keys appears in a link.
    How can I get the foreign key fields normally?

Here is my model class :

```
@Table(name = "affecter")
@Data
@Entity
public class Affecter implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "dateEntree", nullable = false)
  private Date dateEntree;

  @Column(name = "dateSortie")
  private Date dateSortie;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idAffaire", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  private Affaire affaire;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idService", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  private Service service;
```

Here is my repository :

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AffecterRepository extends JpaRepository<Affecter, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Affecter>{
    //Long countById();


    @Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Affecter a WHERE a.service.id = ?1 AND a.dateSortie=null")
    @RestResource(path = "/byService")
    public List<Affecter> findAffecterByService(@Param("idS") Integer service);

}
```

And this is my JSON array returned by the link : http://localhost:8080/affecters

```
id: 2,
dateEntree: "2019-06-19T00:00:00.000+0000",
dateSortie: null,
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/affecters/2"
},
affecter: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/affecters/2"
},
affaire: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/affecters/2/affaire"
},
service: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/affecters/2/service"
}
}
```

Comment: You have to map the foreign key columns as attributes in the entity as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map the foreign key columns as attributes in the entity as well but as read only:

```
@Column(name = "idAffaire", insertable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer idAffaire;

@Column(name = "idService", insertable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer idService;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it make an error, Column not allow on a ManyToOne property

Comment: Have a look at my answer. This is not on the ManyToOne reference. These are two additional fields